# Mac vs Linux (Ubuntu) .ssh config for github

Tags: linux, macos, git, github, ssh

I have following configuration on Mac OS X in `/Users/andi/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile "~/.ssh/githubik"
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And I easily can run easily `git clone git@github:andilab/mbf.git`

I try very same configuration on Ubunut (14.04 on EC2). The config is in `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` and wwhen I run `git clone git@github:andilab/mbf.git` I get:

```
Cloning into 'mbf'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: git:github_.com_:...

Comment: @bmargulies It was not the reason! Read the answer, and consider not punishing me with -points...

Answer (score 2):

all right I know it sucks answering own questions on SO, but maybe it will help somebody. I was sudo-ing on server, so  the configs for `ubuntu` user were not considered when playing as `root`.

**Solution**: provide configuraiton for right user, and everything works.